# Canvas drawing off center, Erase doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a JavaScript that allows a user to draw with their mouse on an HTML5 canvas (similar to MS Paint).

Right now, I have 2 problems:

1. The drawing feature only works if the HTML5 canvas element is positioned at the top left corner (0, 0) of the web page, otherwise it doesn't work at all OR the drawing is off center.
2. I'm unable to erase the drawing. When I erase the drawing it erases BUT as soon as I start drawing again, it comes back.

My code is below:

HTML Canvas

```
<canvas id="can1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>1
```

JavaScript for Canvas Drawing

```
// Variables
var x1;
var y1;
var isPressed = false;
var myCanvas;
var myContext;

function startCanvas() {

    // Canvas stuff
    myCanvas = document.getElementById("can1");
    myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // Specify a black background, and white lines that are 3 pixels thick.
    myContext.fillStyle = '#fff';
    myContext.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    myContext.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    myContext.lineWidth = 3;
    myContext.fill();
}

function functionMouseDown(e) {
    // Get coordinates
    x1 = e.clientX
    y1 = e.clientY;

    isPressed = true;
}

function functionMouseMove(e) {
    // If mouse is down and moved start drawing line
    if (isPressed == true) {
        drawLine(e);
    }
}

function functionMouseUp() {
    // Stop drawing line
    isPressed = false;
    //myContext.closePath();
    //myContext.stroke();
}

function drawLine(e) {
    // Draw line
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;

    myContext.strokeStyle = '#cc0000';
    myContext.lineWidth = 1;
    myContext.moveTo(x1, y1);
    myContext.lineTo(x, y);
    myContext.stroke();

    // Set start coordinates to current coordinates
    x1 = x;
    y1 = y;
}
```

JavaScript that I use to erase canvas:

```
myContext.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Comment: Well structured question but you might want to change the title to reflect your actual problem.

Also, looks like you're not compensating for the position of the canvas itself when you calc ```x``` & ```y```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set the off set of the canvas using myCanvas.offsetLeft and myCanvas.offsetTop.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to accomplish this

```
function relMouseCoords(event){/*needs fixing for general case*/
    var totalOffsetX = 0
    var totalOffsetY = 0
    var canvasX = 0
    var canvasY = 0
    var currentElement = this

    do{
        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft
        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop
    }
    while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

    canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX
    canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY

    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relMouseCoords = relMouseCoords;
```

then

```
var cord = e.target.relMouseCoords(e);
x1 = cord.x; 
y1 = cord.y;
...
var cord = e.target.relMouseCoords(e);
var x = cord.x;
var y =cord.y;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/u3rvT/1/